# Laptop locks screen instead of hibernates

Tags: kubuntu, hibernate

I am having hard time trying to hibernate kubuntu 12.04
It doesn't hibernate. instead it goes to the lock screen only.

I checked the swap and it's 10G and active.
I tried to hibernate using the command "sudo pm-hibernate" and it worked. but, I want a better fix without using commands.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If hibernatian works by using `sudo pm-hibernate` command when you want to hibernate.

You can enable the hibernate option in the menus. To do that, use your favorite text editor to create `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`. Add the following to the file and save:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

<sup>Source: [helpdeskgeek](http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/return-the-hibernate-option-to-the-ubuntu-12-04-system-menu/)</sup>

Comment: The hibernate option is already enabled.
but it just locks the screen without hibernation

Comment: What Kubuntu release are you running?

Comment: I am running Kubuntu 12.04

Comment: "The document could not be saved, as it was not possible to write to /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla. Check that you have write access to this file or that enough disk space is available." That's the message I get when I try this. Any help? I have 100 GB of space and I made sure I had permissions set to write. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: This should either be a question or a comment in the other answer.  However, did you use sudo when editing the file?

Comment: @Stuart, if you want to use something like gedit, the regular Ubuntu text edit, you would open a terminal with Alt+Ctrl+T and enter `gksudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla . That will open a text editor window on your desktop and allow you to save the file when you are done editing it, despite that fact that it is protected. sudo and gksudo are prefix commands to be used with care when changing the system.