# Hibernate on Ubuntu (18.04) - s2disk working, but KDE buttons not

Tags: kubuntu, hibernate

**Summary**

I can hibernate my system using `s2disk`, but not when using `pm-hibernate` or any KDE button. In latter case the system boots like it was a normal shutdown.
`s2disk` works, but when resuming I unfortunately have no password prompt.

**Specs** (though I had same issues on 17.10)

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
Linux 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Question**

How can I either tell Kubuntu to use `s2disk` for hibernation, or tell `pm-hibernate` to *use* `s2disk` (assuming that this is the correct way).

Comment: Funny thing: I've read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate and set added `disk` to `/sys/power/state`. After saving my system immediately went to hibernate, and woke up on its own.
Though the content of the file is back to `freeze mem disk`, hibernation works now when hitting the `hibernate` button in KDE.
But still, there's no password prompt, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I could solve this issue:

As mentioned in my comment, I had to set the content of `/sys/power/state` to be `disk`.

```
sudo nano /sys/power/state
```

Insert `disk`. Then - for what reasons ever - the (at least mine) system goes to hibernate, and comes back directly.

Then I checked `settings --> Desktop Behaviour --> Activation --> "Lock screen on resume".

After that I've installed `kscreenlocker-dev`

```
sudo apt install kscreenlocker-dev
```

Once restarted, I could click on KDE's hibernate button and resume - including a password prompt - pretty fine.

Comment: Are you saying the contents of your /sys/power/state is only `disk` or is it `freeze mem disk`?

Comment: `disk` only. But, as said, it mysteriously sets the value back to `freeze mem disk`, yet I can hibernate since this particular change.