# Set pm-hibernate as default in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, power-management, hibernate

With the help of questions here at SO ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023179/force-hibernate-using-hibernate-instead-of-pm-hibernate), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation#94963)) I managed to find a way of hibernate my computer. The only approach that worked was with `uswsusp`, which made `pm-hibernate` work, but now I can only hibernate my machine via the command line even after creating the sleep module:

`sudo cat /etc/pm/config.d/00sleep_module
SLEEP_MODULE=uswsusp`

How do I make `pm-hibernate` the default method? So that when I press the hibernate option in the menu or close the lid `pm-hibernate` is used instead of systemctl?

Comment: I am in same boat. With no answer so far

Comment: @Dr.Xperience Hi guys, same issue here. `pm-hibernate` works great, while the default `systemctl hibernate` randomly gets stuck on blank screen. I would like to replace the default command with `pm-hibernate` so that I could use it with the power button. I tried [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320675/how-to-use-uswsusp-for-standby-hibernation-with-systemd-debian/386837#386837) but with no success... Do you guys have updates?

Comment: @FrancescoBoccardo I moved to Ubuntu 18.10 and ditched pm-hibernate and uswusp all together in favour of systemctl hibernate. I highly recommend moving to ubuntu18.10 it fixed many other issues for me.

Comment: @Dr.Xperience Yea well, I'd rather stay on a LTS release, but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the idea of [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320675/how-to-use-uswsusp-for-standby-hibernation-with-systemd-debian/386837#386837) I have managed to get my systemctl-hibernate service using plain `pm-hibernate`.

I am currently on Ubuntu 18.10.

Change the content systemd-hibernate.service file (`systemctl edit systemd-hibernate.service`) to:

```
[Unit]
Description=Hibernate
Documentation=man:systemd-suspend.service(8)
DefaultDependencies=no
    
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/pm-hibernate
```

Reload the daemon

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

and go for it

```
systemctl hibernate
```

If you are using gnome and want to install the hibernate-button (which actually works with this solution) check out the solution presented [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/add-hibernate-option-ubuntu-18-04/).